Weird entity framework DbUpdateConcurrencyException
Experiencing weird DbUpdateConcurrencyExceptions, on deployed applications. The exceptions are being raised for both insert and update. The strange thing it's sometimes works well for a period of time..
Locally can not reproduce it.
Code:
public Task<Dto> InsertAsync(Dto item)
{
    var dbItem = _mapper.Map<DbItem>(item);
    _dbContext.SomeDb.Add(dbItem);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return Task.FromResult(item);
}

public class DbItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    ... Other string properties.
}

Context configuration:
builder.Entity<DbItem>().HasKey(b => b.Id);

Unfortunately can not reproduce locally.

Sounds like a Scope-Issue. Can you post relevant DI-Configuration?

First of all, what is the full exception message? Secondly, why are you not awaiting the call to SaveChangesAsync and instead returning Task.FromResult?

Try this out for dbconcurrency exception
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

Plus, check Microsoft's official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#resolving-concurrency-conflicts
This helped me in handling db concurrency exception in a better way.

Why would SaveChangesAsync perform optimistic concurrency just like that?
